# Levenshtein distance algorithm's variant: calculate distance to make a string to be longest substring of other

Tags: algorithm, levenshtein-distance

Are there any algorithm similar to Levenshtein distance algorithm, which can be described:

Original: the minimum number of single-character edits required to change one word into the other

What I want: the minimum number of single-character edits required to change one word `to become the longest substring of the other`

For eg:

```
s1 = "stak"

s2 = "stackoverflow"
```

- 1st modification: replace `k` character to `c` to make s1 to be `stac`, distance = 1, length = 4
- 2nd modification: add `c` between `a` and `k` to make s1 to be `stack`, distance = 1, length = 5
- 3rd modification: remove `k` to make `s1` to be `sta`, distance = 1, length = 3

all 3 modifications have distance = 1 but the 2nd makes `s1` to become longest substring with smallest distance to `s2`, so this is the modification what I want and `stack` is the string what I need

```cs
string Levenshtein(string s1, string s2);
```

my goal of this research to suggest the correct result set from user input which is entered a part of result string

Comment: Is not clear what you're trying to maximize/minimize. if distance is the priority or the length? I guess you first trying to have the minimal number of operations for inverting one string to be substring of the other and between the minimal solutions, you're looking for the longest one. if so, please make it clear. Furthermore, I would define what kind of operation you consider as edits operations. delete, adding and replace character on both strings are viable?

Comment: the priority is distance and then the length (order by distance asc, length desc). if there're many min operations then compare the substrings' length. accept operations are delete, add and replace which is similar to original Levenshtein algorithm

Comment: I have updated the main question above, do you have any comments on it @JackRaBeat